# Call plugin when new related record added

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

In MS Dynamics CRM 2013, I want to call some server side logic (plugin) on refreshing of subgrid or when new record added in the subgrid.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What specifically do you want to accomplish by calling this server side code?

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a plugin for a client-side event like the refresh of a subgrid (not entirely true, there is the `RetrieveMultiple` message but will be a bit painful to understand when it is called by the subgrid and will degrade a bit the system performance).

Different situation when a record is added in the subgrid, in this case you can consider the `Associate` message (and `Disassociate` as well) to start your plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can not call plug-in form client side. but when grid refreshing you call the record save function of ms-crm client (Xrm.page.data.entity.save()) that call your plug-in.